# Abort ajaxcall if it is not null

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    var ajaxCall;

    if (ajaxCall != null)
        ajaxCall.abort();

    ajaxCall = $.post('../etc..
```

I run this code in a function. However, `ajaxCall` is always undefined, even when its running (thos occurs when clicking the button who triggers the call before its complete). Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do (you need to assign the variable before calling `abort()` on it) (maybe your code is like this but from your example it seems to be in a different order)

```
var ajaxCall = $.post('../etc..');

if (ajaxCall != null)
    ajaxCall.abort();
```

Comment: I declared it outside my function and it worked. Your code will always abort the call.

Comment: @Johan yes of course it will always abort the call, it was just to show why `ajaxCall` was always `undefined`

Comment: True, but what i asked for was a way to abort the "old" call, not the current. But it was a bad explanation from my side. Thanks anyway